# Operator overloading on inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, stream, operator-overloading

Here are 2 classes

```
class B
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, B& obj)
    {
        in >> obj.x;
        return in;
    }
};

class D: public B
{
private:
    int y;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, D& obj)
    {
        //?
    }
};
```

Is there any way that I can overload the `>>` operator in class D so it will be able to access the element x in B?

Comment: To be more specific, make `x` protected ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you appear to be trying to do, you could also do this:

```
class B
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, B& obj)
    {
        in >> obj.x;
        return in;
    }
};

class D: public B
{
private:
    int y;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, D& obj)
    {
        B* cast = static_cast<B*>(&D); //create pointer to base class
        in >> *B; //this calls the operator>> function of the base class
    }
};
```

Although there are probably other reasons to make `x` protected instead of private anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that I coverload the >> operator in class D so he will be able to access the element x in B?

Don't make `x` private.

By making it private, you're explicitly saying that access to it is restricted to `class B` and its friends.  And from your question, it seems that you don't want that.

If it were `protected` instead, you could access it as `obj.x`.

Comment: I'm afraid this wouldn't work, because `operator >>` here is a friend of `D`, not a member function

Answer (score 0):

x needs to be protected. Otherwise it is not accessible directly from D.

```
class B
{
protected:
    int x;
```

Then you can do

```
class D: public B
{
private:
    int y;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, D& obj)
    {
        in >> obj.x;
        return in;
    }
};
```

Comment: `x` is inherited by `D` in the sense that `D` has an `x` data member. It is just not accessible.